# How to get coordinates from the CaretIndex in WPF C#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, caret, onkeyup

I need to get the exact coordinates of the point where the caret of my multi-line `Textbox` is placed.

Suppose I'm writing a new character in the `Textbox`, then the coordinates should be changed.

P.S. I want these coordinates on the KeyUp event of the `Textbox`, not on the `Mouse` events.

Thanks.

Comment: Create mouseposition.

Comment: Didn't get that much, can you please explain in more depth. Thanks

Comment: MousePosition mousePosition = new MousePosition()?

Comment: Not able to get anything like MousePosition, pal.

Comment: I think that you never tried to do anything

Comment: @MarcoSalerno appreciate your help. Thanks, I'll find my way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextBox` provides a method for obtaining the bounds of the character at any position in the text.  If you pass in `CaretIndex`, the left side of the rectangle corresponds to the left edge of the caret.

```
var rect = textBox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(textBox.CaretIndex);
```

You can then use `rect.TopLeft` or `rect.BottomLeft` to get the coordinates of the upper or lower end of the caret.  Note that you will need to do some sanity checks.  A proper implementation would look something like this:

```
    private Point? GetCaretPosition()
    {
        var rect = textBox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(textBox.CaretIndex);
        var location = rect.TopLeft /* or BottomLeft */;

        if (double.IsInfinity(location.X) || double.IsInfinity(location.Y))
            return null;

        return location;
    }
```

Comment: Bravo, I just used that and it&#39;s working, thanks by the way, I have used BottomRight coordinates. Cheers to WPF.

Answer (score -1):

Add a KeyUp event on your text box/ area:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="104,80,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" KeyUp="TextBox_KeyUp"/>
```

Then manage the mouse position on the event handler:

```
 private void TextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Point myMouse = Mouse.GetPosition(this);

       //do something with the mouse position
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This tells you where the mouse cursor is, it doesn't tell you where the text caret is.

Comment: Trying this, will let you know.

Comment: @BhavikJadav I'm not sure what technique you used, but if you didn't use `GetRectFromCharacterIndex` then you should see my answer.  That would be the 'proper' way to do it.